# Is there a way to define MACRO in C++ to generate content differentiated by input type?

Tags: c++, macros

Refer the following code, I hope the macro 'bar' can be **precompiled** to what the comments  show.

```
#define bar(x) if(x is int) foo_int(x); else if (x is float) foo_float; else (x);

int main()
{
    bar(123); // -> foo_int(123);
    bar(1.0f); // -> foo_float(1.0f);
    bar(false); // -> false;
}
```

Comment: The two real solutions to this problem are: 1) If `bar` acts the same, just the parameter type is different, make it a Template function 2) If the `bar` behavior is different for each type, make overloads of the function.

Comment: Seriously, why a macro is this is C++? Or did you mean C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A macro is the wrong tool for this job (and for most other jobs). You'd do this with a template, overloaded for whichever types need special treatment:

```
template <typename T> T bar(T x) {return x;}  // generic template
int bar(int x) {return foo_int(x);}           // overload for int
float bar(float x) {return foo_float(x);}     // overload for float
```

Answer (score 2):

in C++14, just do:

```
auto bar(int i) { return foo_int(i); }
auto bar(float f) { return foo_float(f); }
template <typename T>
auto bar(T&& t) { return std::forward<T>(t); }
```

in C++11

```
#define Return(x) decltype(x) {return x;}

auto bar(int i) -> Return(foo_int(i))
auto bar(float f) -> Return(foo_float(f))
template <typename T>
auto bar(T&& t) -> Return(std::forward<T>(t))
```